# Jquery/javascript named index array with array association

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, indexing, named

I want to know if its possible (and correct) to construct a named index array that is associated with other arrays.

E.g.,

```js
var signOptionSet = [];
signOptionSet['basic'] = ['Sign Width', 'Sign Height', 'Sign Depth', 'Base Material', 'Finish'];
signOptionSet['advanced'] = ['Area', 'Perimeter', 'Lighting'];
```

How would I access something like 'Sign Height' in signOptionSet['basic']?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to know if its possible...

Yes, although the way you're using it, you wouldn't want an array, you'd just want an object (`{}`) (see below).

> ...(and correct)...

Some would argue that using an array and then adding non-index properties to it is not correct. There's nothing *technically* wrong with it, provided you understand that some things (such as `JSON.stringify`) won't see those non-index properties.

> How would I access something like 'Sign Height' in signOptionSet['basic']?

It's the second entry, so index 1, of the array you've assigned to `signOptionSet['basic']`, so:

```
var x = signOptionSet['basic'][1];
```

or

```
var x = signOptionSet.basic[1];
```

---

Using an object, and using property name literals as there's no need for strings here, would look like this:

```
var signOptionSet = {
    basic: ['Sign Width', 'Sign Height', 'Sign Depth', 'Base Material', 'Finish'],
    advanced: ['Area', 'Perimeter', 'Lighting']
};
```

You *can* use strings, though, if you prefer:

```
var signOptionSet = {
    "basic": ['Sign Width', 'Sign Height', 'Sign Depth', 'Base Material', 'Finish'],
    "advanced": ['Area', 'Perimeter', 'Lighting']
};
```

Both single and double quotes are valid in JavaScript (single quotes wouldn't be in JSON, but this isn't JSON, it's JavaScript):

```
var signOptionSet = {
    'basic': ['Sign Width', 'Sign Height', 'Sign Depth', 'Base Material', 'Finish'],
    'advanced': ['Area', 'Perimeter', 'Lighting']
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You access the value **'Sign Height'** like

```
alert(signOptionSet['basic'][1]) // 'Sign Height'
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/03go7Lg0/1/)

Comment: This worked, but the answer by Crowder was more complete to my query.

Comment: @Matthew6 His answer is exactly what you should seek to understand to go about your trouble. :)